# Keras model.evaluate_generator results nearly twice real accuracy?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

### UPDATE: see new section below.

When I run model.evaluate_generator it gives me results of 92%. But if I run model.predict_classes on every test image and count the correct classification vs incorrect classification, I get 49%...

Clearly something is wrong. Am I misunderstanding the evaluate_generator results, or am I not doing predict_classes right?

Here is the model.evaluate_generator call (it gets 92%):

```
print("test_generator from Directory");
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory( 
test_dir, 
target_size=(200, 200), 
batch_size=20, 
class_mode='categorical') 

# finally evaluate this model on the test data 
results = model.evaluate_generator( 
test_generator, 
steps=1) 

print('Final test accuracy:', (results[1]*100.0))
```

For the comparison, I test every file and compare to the correct classification (this gets 49%):

```
  img_path = os.path.join(bol, file)
  print(img_path)
  image = load_img(img_path, target_size=(200, 200)) 
  image = img_to_array(image) 
  image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
  image = preprocess_input(image)
  # classify the image 
  print("classifying image...") 
  y_hat = model.predict_classes(image) 
  print(y_hat[0])
  idtype = newdict[y_hat[0]]  #this part is to match predicted class with true class
  destpath = os.path.join(bol, idtype, file)      
  print(idtype)
  if idtype == cat[1]:
    correct = correct + 1
  count = count + 1
  factor = correct / count
  print(str(count) + " - " + str(correct) + " = " + str(factor))
```

The full code is here: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/klondon/food_6_VGG_aug_plus_id.py.txt

### EDIT:

With the help of Matias Valdenegro in the comments, I have fixed some bugs with my code. It now uses 'Softmax' output and categorical cross-entropy loss. Full code here: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/klondon/food_6_VGG_aug_plus_id_cat.py.txt

However - The core issue remains. There is a huge difference between the results from evaluate_generator (now 71%) and a manual test of the same images using predict_classes (53%).

Are there other issues with my code?

### EDIT 2:

I have tried setting shuffle=False and batch_size = 1 for testing, but the issue remains. evaluate_generator still returns ~70% while predict_classes is ~50%

### EDIT 3:

Fixed code here: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/klondon/food_6_VGG_aug_plus_id_fix.py.txt

Issue was: I shouldn't use preprocess_input in predict_classes unless that is used in training and validation also. Also, I should use image /=255 to match the training & validation images.

Comment: Seems you have a multi-label model, in that case you should not use predict_classes as there can be more than one correct class in each prediction.

Comment: What should I use instead of predict_classes? Also - I have 6 types - and I dont think a single image can have multiple categories.

Comment: Then you are using the wrong model, because you have a multi-label model (sigmoid output + binary cross-entropy loss).

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: Softmax output and categorical cross-entropy loss.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try.

Comment: Just to clarify - I should have model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy'..) and on the last layer of my model, activation='softmax' ?

Comment: I have flow_from_directory class_mode='binary' - is that ok?

Comment: Yes, that's right. No, class mode should be categorical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing everything, you still don't have the `preprocess_input` in the `ImageDataGenerator`.

So, your manually loaded images are different from the generated images.

Create the `ImageDataGenerator` with the preprocessing function:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
```

Or remove the preprocessing function from the manual loading (if your model was already trained with such generators).

Comment: Do I also need to rescale=1./255 on my image before predict_classes? I had assumed that preprocess_input did that.

Comment: Interesting question. I'd use only the exact same preprocessing function without rescaling. It happens that `preprocess_input` may be doing more things, it may be rescaling into a range from -1 to +1, or it may be keeping a 255 scale but centering values. It depends on where you're getting this function from.

Comment: Use either "only rescale" in both cases, or "only preprocess" in both cases.

Comment: Fixed it! Your suggestion helped greatly but the issue was a simple bug. I shouldn't have been using preprocess_input, and I should have been using image /= 255. Working code here: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/klondon/food_6_VGG_aug_plus_id_fix.py.txt